# Python Google Sheets API

Tags: python, google-sheets, data-science

So I have this google sheets API, and I am grabbing data from it and running a KS test. However, I only want to run the KS test on a number. But, the string consists of words as well. For instance, here you go

```
 2020-09-15 00:05:13,chemsense,co,concentration,-0.51058,
2020-09-15 00:05:43,chemsense,co,concentration,-0.75889,
2020-09-15 00:06:09,chemsense,co,concentration,-1.23385,
2020-09-15 00:06:33,chemsense,co,concentration,-1.23191,
2020-09-15 00:06:58,chemsense,co,concentration,-0.94495,
2020-09-15 00:07:23,chemsense,co,concentration,-1.16024,
```

If I have this as a string, How would I run a KS test on just the last numbers of each line. For instsnace, I only want to run the KS test on -.51,-.75,-1.23,-1.23,-.94,-1.16

Here is a screenshot of my Google sheet:
[image]

Here is some of my code:

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import  ServiceAccountCredentials
import re


np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')
def estimate_cdf (col,bins=10,):
    print (col)
    # 'col'
    # 'bins'

    hist, edges = np.histogram(col)
    csum = np.cumsum(hist)



    return csum/csum[-1], edges
    print (csum)



scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open("sheet1").sheet1  # Opens the spreadhseet

data = sheet.get_all_records()


row = sheet.row_values(3)  # Grab a specific row






number_regex = r'^-?\d+\.?\d*$'





col = sheet.col_values(3)  # Get a specific column print (col)

col2= sheet.col_values(4)
dolphin= estimate_cdf(adjusted := [float(i) for i in col if re.match(i, number_regex)], len(adjusted))



print(col)
print(col2)




shtest =stats.shapiro(col)
print(shtest)




#thelight= sheet.update_cell(5,6,col)
#print(thelight)

k2test =stats.ks_2samp(col, col2, alternative='two-sided', mode='auto')
print(k2test)
```

And here is some of my error message:

temperature,64.79599999999999,65.03830769230765', '2020-09-25 11:38:51,metsense,htu21d,temperature,64.85,65.01338461538458', '2020-09-25 11:39:16,metsense,htu21d,temperature,64.994,64.99538461538458', '2020-09-25 11:39:42,metsense,htu21d,temperature,65.066,64.98015384615381', '2020-09-25 11:40:06,metsense,htu21d,temperature,64.94,64.95799999999996', '2020-09-25 11:40:31,metsense,htu21d,temperature,64.976,64.93861538461535', '2020-09-25 11:40:57,metsense,htu21d,temperature,65.066,64.93307692307688', '2020-09-25 11:41:22,metsense,htu21d,temperature,65.048,64.93584615384611', '2020-09-25 11:41:48,metsense,htu21d,temperature,64.994,64.92753846153843', '2020-09-25 11:42:12,metsense,htu21d,temperature,64.976,64.93169230769227', '2020-09-25 11:42:37,metsense,htu21d,temperature,64.94,64.9441538461538', '2020-09-25 11:43:03,metsense,htu21d,temperature,64.994,64.95523076923072', '2020-09-25 11:43:28,metsense,htu21d,temperature,64.9']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/james/PycharmProjectsfreshproj/shapiro wilks.py", line 60, in 
shtest =stats.shapiro(col)
File "C:\Users\james\PycharmProjectsfreshproj\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\morestats.py", line 1676, in shapiro
a, w, pw, ifault = statlib.swilk(y, a[:N//2], init)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ',,,,,'

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

Given strings coming from Google Sheets API, run kstest on the last number of each string.

## Solution

A better way would be getting the numbers straight from Google Sheets API, store them and feed to `stats.kstest`.

### Working with your existing strings

You can split the string using [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) then covert the it to float.

#### Example

```
>>> s = '2020-09-15 00:05:43,chemsense,co,concentration,-0.75889,'

>>> s.split(',')
['2020-09-15 00:05:43', 'chemsense', 'co', 'concentration', '-0.75889', '']

>>> s.split(',')[4] # get the number (5th item in the list)
'-0.75889'

>>> float(s.split(',')[4]) # convert to float type
-0.75889

>>> round(float(s.split(',')[4]), 2) # round to 2 decimal place
-0.76
```

```
from scipy import stats

# Assuming strings coming back from API are in a list
str = [
'2020-09-15 00:05:13,chemsense,co,concentration,-0.51058,',
'2020-09-15 00:05:43,chemsense,co,concentration,-0.75889,',
'2020-09-15 00:06:09,chemsense,co,concentration,-1.23385,',
'2020-09-15 00:06:33,chemsense,co,concentration,-1.23191,',
'2020-09-15 00:06:58,chemsense,co,concentration,-0.94495,',
'2020-09-15 00:07:23,chemsense,co,concentration,-1.16024,'
]

x = []

for s in str:
  x.append(float(s.split(',')[4]))

stats.kstest(x, 'norm')
```

Comment: Thanks! one thing however, the strings could very well change so is there a way to do this that it will work for any string in the google api?

Comment: @JamesWatterton It really depends on what the string will looks like. Like I said, a better way would be getting the numbers straight from Google Sheets API. Is '2020-09-15 00:05:13,chemsense,co,concentration,-0.51058,' currently all in one google sheet cell?

Comment: yes, all of that information is in one cell. Basically it is one line per cell so 2020-09-15 00:05:13,chemsense,co,concentration,-0.51058 would all be in a cell

Comment: To be honest , I would prefer your way, if that is possible.

Comment: @JamesWatterton Your follow up question is not specific enough. What's the input going to look like and what's the output? Are strings you get always comma separated? etc. Without specifying the question there's no way I could propose anything that works universally

Comment: Please also read about https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask @JamesWatterton

Comment: The input of my call is going to look like ' 2020-09-15 00:05:13,chemsense,co,concentration,-0.51058 ' . There are basically 100 of these strings that are similar. They are all in one column. I store all of those values in a variable 'col' I would then run a shapiro wilks test of normality (in conjunction with the ks test) using the shapiro.stats(col) function. The output of my function is the result of the statistics tests.

Comment: I have updated my question: hopefully that is helpful for you.

Comment: any more help would be nice @yibo

Comment: Could somebody please answer?? Kinda urgent. Been waiting a week. Not tryna be rude.

Comment: are you still gonna answer? @yibo